# Как правильно делить числа

Tags: php, float, деление

```
$a = 70577570;
$b = 1000000000000;

$c = $a / $b;
echo $c;
```

В итоге $c содержит 7.057757E-5, а мне надо чтобы содержало 0.00007057757.
Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7.057757E-5 и 0.00007057757 - это одно и тоже. Просто разная запись числа. А число одно и тоже.

Если же Вам для вывода нужно, тогда просто попросите php все вывести так, как хочется

```
$a = 70577570;
$b = 1000000000000;

$c = $a / $b;
printf("%.11f", $c);
```